# How to find electric field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

Suppose a charged hollow  hemisphere with a disc having same charge q attached on the base and have radius r. Then what will be the field at point d on the axis . Can we proceed by integration?

Comment: Flagged -- physics-SE is not a homework-help site. You should ask about a specific concept, and we can try to clear it up for you, but asking how to do problems (especially standard problems), is not on-topic. At any rate, what would make you think you cannot proceed by integration?

Comment: Yes you can proceed using integration, but you will also need to use the principle of superposition(obviously).